# Disable all AJAX / Websocket data requests on a site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, debugging, websocket

I have the following webpage that loads a bunch of ajax or websocket requests when the page is done loading. This is due to the constant updating of the on page chatroom and constant updating of the prices in the charts.

https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_ardr

Is there a way to disable the browser from fetching the chatbox data and price updates of the chart? Every time I load the page, it either freezes or lags. I just want to be able to keep the forms intact on the page as I would like to submit them without all the noise.

What is something I can run in the console that can just stop all the activity on the page without messing up the form submissions?

Comment: Please enlighten us. You have a page you are in full control over. You have added a chat session and price updates to it and now you want to disable that? Why not just not have it in the first place since you are trying to kill the functionality anyway?

Comment: @mplungjan According to the question it's because it causes his browser to "freeze or lag". He still needs to be able to send orders.

Comment: I understand - but do not understand why he asks how to disable them when he can just load them after the rest of the page loads or remove them

Answer (score 1):

All AJAX requests use XMLHttpRequest internally, except in IE.
You can override the native XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest = function(){}
XMLHttpRequest.prototype = {
    open: function(){},
    send: function(){}
}
```

For IE, you can disable XMLHTTP under Security settings.
For disabling WebSocket I used the --disable-web-sockets flag while starting Chrome.